# combine multiple same echo's to one echo from for loop in bash

Tags: shell-script, echo, for

I'm creating a monitoring script that looks at results from multiple hosts in for loop and then echo's OK or NOT OK... If all resulted to OK then I want to combine the message to single OK else NOT OK. Here's what currently works:

Script:

```
for HOST in $HOST1 $HOST2 $HOST2
do
    HEARTBEAT=$(${LDAPSEARCH} -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT} -D "${USER}" -w $${PASS} -b "" -s base "(objectClass=*)" | grep dn: | sed 's/dn:/dn/g')
    if [ $HEARTBEAT = 'dn' ]; then
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "NOT OK"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
$OK
$OK
$OK
```

Else Output:

```
$NOT OK
$NOT OK
$NOT OK
```

Desired Output:

```
$OK
else
$NOT OK
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this - a little re-organizing of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for HOST in $HOST1 $HOST2 $HOST2
do
    HEARTBEAT=$(${LDAPSEARCH} -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT} -D "${USER}" -w $${PASS} -b "" -s base "(objectClass=*)" | grep dn: | sed 's/dn:/dn/g')
    if [ ! $HEARTBEAT = 'dn' ]; then
        echo "NOT OK"
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "ok"
```

This script will print a single `NOT OK` after encountering the first incorrect `HOST` and will print a single `OK` if there no incorrect `HOSTs`.

Comment: Great... it was simple solution... Thanks bunch Arkadiusz... that worked.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. If you like this answer please mark it as accepted so that other users know it's solved.